# C# "Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog."

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code from within a form. This function is suppose to open another form I have created as a dialog box but I keep getting the error:

> Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog
>   box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling
>   showDialog.

I have looked through all the form properties and cannot find this anyplace. What am I missing? Using Visual Studio 2015 and a winforms application with .net 4

```
    private void disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowDialog(new ManagerWarning());
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually trying to call the `ShowDialog` method of the current view, with the `new ManagerWarning()` as parameter (effectively, trying to open the current view as a modal, with the new form as parent).

Create instance of form `ManagerWarning` and try to run this way

```
private void disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagerWarning m = new ManagerWarning();
        m.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That works, but what is the purpose of the ShowDialog command then?

Comment: @DavidBentley - When you call `ShowDialog` as you did in your code, it is the same as `this.ShowDialog`.  You are trying to call `ShowDialog` on your already visible form.

Comment: if you want a form to show as a dialog means when it show as dialog without closing this you can not access other portion, I really use it for show some important info so that user can not minimize or access other things by ignoring this, if you don't want this feature then you can use `m.Show()` for this case

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar warning, but in the slightly different area.

I fix it this way:

```
if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Settings1.Default.PreviousPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.saveDialog.FileName);
            Settings1.Default.Save();

            // Code writing to the new file...
        }
```